# React lazy does not cause splitting bundle in chunks

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading

As in the title, I'm trying to use React.lazy feature which works in my my other project. But not in this one, I don't know what I'm missing here. All works just fine, no errors, no warnings. But for some reason I don't see my bundle split in chunks.

Here's my implementation:

```js
import React, { Component, Suspense } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { getApps } from '../../actions/apps';
import './_apps.scss';

const AppItemComponent = React.lazy(() => import('../AppItem'));

class Apps extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { getApps } = this.props;

    getApps(3);
  }

  renderAppItem = () => {
    const { apps } = this.props;

    return apps && apps.map((item, i) =>  {
      return (
        <Suspense fallback={<div>loading...</div>} key={i}>
          <AppItemComponent
            index={i + 1}
            item={item}
          />
        </Suspense>
      );
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { apps } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="apps__section">
        <div className="apps__container">
          <div className="apps__header-bar">
            <h3 className="apps__header-bar--title">Apps</h3>
            <Link className="apps__header-bar--see-all link" to="/apps">{`see all (${apps.length})`}</Link>
          </div>
          {this.renderAppItem()}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ apps }) => {
  return { apps };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    getApps: quantity => dispatch(getApps(quantity)),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Apps);
```

I'm doing this in react-create-app app and in react v16.6, react-dom v16.6.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Maybe you are importing it like e.g. `import AppItem from '../../AppItem';` somewhere else in the code?

Comment: Are you suggesting that if there is another place with regular (old way) import of the same component it'd prevent code to be split?

Comment: I don't see why that should happen from the code currently in your question, but let's say you imported a component `Home` in your `Apps` file, and `Home` imported `AppItem`, then that would prevent it from being code split into a separate bundle.

Comment: You're right. It prevents from splitting. I see chunks now :) The only issue left now is that my main bundle file seems to have exactly the same size as before, ie. 550 kb (the other small chunk has 2.7kb but this is not deducted from the main bundle)

Comment: Hey guys, it would be nice if we have these comments as an answer. If you don't want to do that I can do.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, as Murakami. The bundle is split in chunks, but main file is still the same size, and the files are still being bundled there as well. I checked the imports but there's nothing left. Any news on this?

Answer (score 4):

1. Check that your component is not imported somewhere with regular import: `import SomeComponent from './path_to_component/SomeComponent';`
2. Check that component is not re-exported somewhere. (For example in index.js (index.ts) file: `export * from './SomeComponent'`) If so, just remove re-export of this component.
3. Check that your export your component as default or use code like this:

   `const SomeComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./path_to_component/SomeComponent').then((module) => ({ default: module.SomeComponent })));`

Comment: Thank you! I spent 3 hours stuck, and the problem was the first point!

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same problem, then I have resolved this case **without using Suspense and lazy(try code below)**, and I can see chunks file. However, after using this way, I try changing my code again with Suspense and lazy. It works!!! and I don't know why it does. Hope that it works for someone find solution for this case.

#### 1 - create file asyncComponent

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

const asyncComponent = (importComponent) => {
   return class extends Component {
      state = {
         component: null,
      };

      componentDidMount() {
         importComponent().then((cmp) => {
            this.setState({ component: cmp.default });
         });
      }

      render() {
         const C = this.state.component;

         return C ? <C {...this.props} /> : null;
      }
   };
};

export default asyncComponent;
```

#### 2 - and in App.js, example:

```
const AuthLazy = asyncComponent(() => import("./containers/Auth/Auth"));
//Route
<Route path="/auth" component={AuthLazy} />
```